# home page changes after spring security plugin installation

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I installed spring security plugin and ran s2-quickstart.

It has generated User and Role domains, and has generated grails-app at

```
../target/work/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2/grails-app
```

Where as my applications grails-app directory is at `../grails-app`

Now my home page is changed to default spring security login and pages are being loaded from grails-app within target directory.

What is the way out of here? 
Can i safely copy contents from grails-app from target directory to my grails-app directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out,
I had to add

```
'/dashBoard/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
```

to my `Config.groovy` as dashboard is the controller from where my home is being called.